# Space after \footnote / \thanks inside \author

Tags: spacing, footnotes, titles, author

If I type:

```
\author{Alpha\thanks{} and Beta\thanks{}}
```

then it is typeset as "Alpha*and Beta*" instead of "Alpha* and Beta*" as I would expect (i.e. there is no space after the first footnote mark).  This does not happen outside `\author`.  The obvious alternative to try:

```
\author{Alpha\thanks{}\ and Beta\thanks{}}
```

does not help.  I can make the desired "Alpha* and Beta*" by resorting to:

```
\author{Alpha\thanks{}\ \ and Beta\thanks{}}
```

but this seems somewhat silly (and makes me worry that on another tex installation it might actually insert two spaces)  Since `\thanks` is clearly intended to be used like this inside `\author`, I feel like I must be missing something about the intended invocation.  How am I supposed to use `\thanks` so that the spacing is correct?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are talking about one of the standard classes.

`classes.dtx` contains:

```
\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
```

compare now to the default, from `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
```

The class code changes the `\hbox` to `\rlap`, which makes the footnote mark have zero width. That's why the space disappears and that's why two spaces look correct.

I don't know the reason for hiding the width of the footnote mark. Perhaps to make the author name (in case of a single author) look "more centered"... Just guessing.

This doesn't happen if you use the `titlepage` option.

To avoid this you can, for instance, override the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@maketitle
  {\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\title{Hello}
\author{Alpha\thanks{} and Beta\thanks{}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```