# no space between \thanks and "and" in maketitle

Tags: titles, authblk

Why is there no space between the `\thanks` and the "and" in this title? How can I get a space to appear there? The point is that two authors are from the same university, but one is the corresponding author and has changed universities, so I have to add a footnote.  Here's what it looks like: [image: examplecode]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}% use option titlepage to get the title on a page of its own
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}  and Richard Row\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe try `\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}\ and Richard Row` (so with `\ `, which is an explicit space)?

Comment: @Marijn unfortunately, it didn't work :/

Comment: I found a duplicate: [Space after \footnote / \thanks inside \author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454960/space-after-footnote-thanks-inside-author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change

```
\author{John Doe\thanks{I am ...} and Richard ...
```

to

```
\author{John Doe\thanks{I am ...} \ and Richard ...
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in \\
Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{December 2017}
\author{John Doe\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department} \ and Richard Row\\ 
\normalsize Magic Department, Richard Miles University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it :)